# Symfony2 Templating without request

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to send an email from a `ContainerAwareCommand` in Symfony2. But I get this exception when the email template is render by:

```
$body = $this->templating->render($template, $data);
```

**Exception**:

```
 ("You cannot create a service ("templating.helper.assets") of an inactive scope ("request").")
```

I found in github that this helper need the request object. Anybody knows how can I to instance the Request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a request, you need to call the templating service directly like this:

```
$this->container->get('templating')->render($template, $data);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. As logn as asset is used (must likely not directly visible in your templates) it needs to have a RequestContext service somehow.

Comment: I am getting same error but this solution doesn't resolve problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942738/erro-you-cannot-create-a-service-templating-helper-assets-of-an-inactive-sco

Comment: This solution worked for me when I'd posted it.  I won't dispute for a minute that it doesn't work with newer versions of Symfony than I had at the time.  When it comes to getting off the beaten path, Symfony is a bit of a moving target.  I've had no time for code for a while so I can't really investigate at the moment, but you might try BetaRide's solution.

Answer (score 19):

You need to set the container into the right scope and give it a (fake) request. In most cases this will be enough:

```
//before you render template add bellow code
$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$this->getContainer()->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

The full story is [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=36627#p138794). If you want to know the details read this [issue on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4514).

Comment: FYI: This was deprecated and is removed in Symfony 3, and was replaced with "setScope" on the service level: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#dependencyinjection

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises because you use *asset()* function in your template.

By default, *asset()* relies on *Request* service to generate urls to your assets (it needs to know what is the base path to you web site or what is the domain name if you use absolute asset urls, for example).

But when you run your application from command line there is no *Request*.

One way to fix this it to explicitely define base urls to your assets in config.yml like this:

```
framework:
  templating:
    assets_base_urls: { http: ["http://yoursite.com"], ssl: ["http://yoursite.com"] }
```

It is important to define both *http* and *ssl*, because if you omit one of them *asset()* will still depend on Request service.

The (possible) downside is that all urls to assets will now be absolute.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation and your solution, it works perfectly ! I tried before this solution http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html but without success

Comment: With this solution, all assets use an absolute url. It can be a problem sometimes.

Comment: This solution is only working if http url and ssl url are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Following [BetaRide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671639/betaride)'s answer put me on the right track but that wasn't sufficient. Then it was complaining: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist."

To create a valid request I've modified it to request the root of the project like so:

```
$request = new Request();
$request->create('/');
$this->container->enterScope('request');
$this->container->set('request', $request, 'request');
```

You might need to call a different route (secured root?), root worked for me just fine.

[Symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#simulating-a-request)

**Bonus addition:**

I had to do so much templating/routing in cli through Symfony2 commands that I've updated the `initializeContainer()` method in AppKernel. It creates a route to the root of the site, sets the router context and fakes a user login:

```
protected function initializeContainer()
{
    parent::initializeContainer();
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {

        $container = $this->getContainer();

        /**
         * Fake request to home page for cli router.
         * Need to set router base url to request uri because when request object
         * is created it perceives the "/portal" part as path info only, not base
         * url and thus router will not include it in the generated url's.
         */
        $request = Request::create($container->getParameter('domain'));
        $container->enterScope('request');
        $container->set('request', $request, 'request');
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $container->get('router')->setContext($context);
        $container->get('router')->getContext()->setBaseUrl($request->getRequestUri());

        /**
         * Fake admin user login for cli. Try database read,
         * gracefully print error message if failed and continue.
         * Continue mainly for doctrine:fixture:load when db still empty.
         */
        try {
            $user = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername('admin');
            if ($user !== null) {
                $token = $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
                $this->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Fake Admin user login failed.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You might not need the last `$container->get('router')->getContext()->setBaseUrl($request->getRequestUri());` part, but I had to do it because my site root was at domain.com/siteroot/ and the router was stripping /siteroot/ away for url generation.

Comment: FYI: This was deprecated and is removed in Symfony 3, and was replaced with "setScope" on the service level: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#dependencyinjection