# Error: You cannot create a service ("templating.helper.assets") of an inactive scope ("request")

Tags: symfony, twig

I am getting below error,

```
  [Twig_Error_Runtime]                                                                                                                                                                                     
  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You cannot create a    service ("templating.helper.assets") of an inactive scope ("request").") in "AcmeMessagingBundle:Comment:email.html.twig".
```

I am rendering twig template from symfony 2 custom console command

Below is my service class which is the event subscriber,I am triggering onCommentAddEmail event by symfony console command to send email,

```
class NotificationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
     private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
         return array(
            'comment.add'     => array('onCommentAddEmail', 0),
         );
     }

     public function onCommentAddEmail(CommentAddEvent $event)
     {
              ...................


             $body = $this->container->get('templating')->render(
            'AcmeMessagingBundle:Comment:email.html.twig',
                array('template' => $template)
             );

     .......


    }

}
```

$body is passed to swiftmailer to send an email.

This is my service defination,

Acme\MessagingBundle\Subscriber\NotificationSubscriber

```
<services>
    <service id="notification_subscriber" class="%notification_subscriber.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Below post says the problem is fixed in symfony 2.1, but I am still getting error,

```
 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4514
```

I have already refereed to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html, I have passed entire container to my service.

Comment: Have a look at the response for a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24409012/1263890)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way but adding this worked for me,

```
    $this->container->enterScope('request');
    $this->container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

Answer (score 6):

As quoted by Stof :

> if you use the request-based asset helper (getting the base url from
>   the request object), it cannot be used from the CLI indeed, as you
>   don't have a request there

Translation, you can't use the `asset` function inside your template if you are intending to use it from the CLI.

Comment: Whats the solution then ?

Comment: You might try replace all asset('img/test.png') by http://mywebsite/img/test.png.

Comment: And what about Unit testing the content of Twig templates?

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because you use *asset()* in your template, which depends on *Request*, and there is no *Request* in command line app.

Quick fix:

```
framework:
  templating:
    assets_base_urls: { http: ["http://yoursite.com"], ssl: ["http://yoursite.com"] }
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24382994/1851915