# Symfony 2.4.2: You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request")

Tags: php, symfony

I just updated a project to Symfony 2.4.2 from 2.2.2. After upgrading the profiler is causing an exception that is displayed inline at the bottom of each page:

'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException' with message **'You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").'**

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException' with message 'You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").' in /var/www/pm/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3776
( ! ) Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException: You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request"). in /var/www/pm/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3776
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0029  239928  {main}( )   ../app_dev.php:0
2   4.0354  53462264    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->terminate( )   ../app_dev.php:18
3   4.0355  53462360    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminate( )   ../bootstrap.php.cache:2283
4   4.0371  53473320    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch( )    ../bootstrap.php.cache:2894
5   4.0377  53477632    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch( )    ../TraceableEventDispatcher.php:138
6   4.0377  53477632    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch( )  ../classes.php:1831
7   4.0377  53477696    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch( )    ../classes.php:1667
8   4.0377  53478048    call_user_func ( )  ../classes.php:1734
9   4.0377  53478088    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}( )    ../classes.php:1734
10  4.0385  53482400    call_user_func ( )  ../TraceableEventDispatcher.php:388
11  4.0385  53482440    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener->onKernelTerminate( )   ../TraceableEventDispatcher.php:388
12  4.0387  53486304    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler->saveProfile( )  ../ProfilerListener.php:136
13  4.0388  53486480    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\EventDataCollector->lateCollect( )   ../Profiler.php:115
14  4.0388  53486544    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->getNotCalledListeners( )   ../EventDataCollector.php:48
15  4.0388  53486752    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->getListeners( )    ../TraceableEventDispatcher.php:166
16  4.0388  53486848    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners( )    ../TraceableEventDispatcher.php:106
17  4.0403  53497920    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad( )    ../classes.php:1807
18  4.0416  53520352    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get( ) ../classes.php:1842
```

It seems that the error is caused when the profiler listens for the kernel termination, but I haven't been able to solve the issue.

What is wrong?

### Edit

Example of a service that has request injection:

```
services:
    property.value.form.resolver.number:
        class: Frisbee\ProductBundle\Form\Resolver\PropertyTypeFormResolverNumber
        arguments: [@form.factory, @request]
        scope: request
```

Comment: Do you have any service where you inject request object?

Comment: Yes, I have quite a few. Wasn't a problem in 2.2. I am aware of http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack, but the stack trace doesn't leave the Symfony namespace.

Comment: @phidah can you post config one of them?

Comment: It seems like you still have somewhere request object injection. Try it, just to make sure: grep "@request" $(find ./src -name "services.yml") | grep -v request_stack

Comment: @denys281 - sure. Just edited the question.

Comment: I tried updating all injections of request to request_stack - didn't solve the problem. Tested with Symfony 2.3.10 and everything works fine.

Comment: If you've replaced all request services dependcy into request_stack one, where the code you've shown come from? Replace all request dependencies into request_stack ones - and I'm sure it will resolve your problem

Comment: @Cyprian it doesn't. The code I pasted was from the current version (before I replaced with `request_stack`).

Comment: have you tried a hard cache clear? (`rm -rf app/cache/dev/*`)

Comment: i'm not sure about it but i'm working with symfony 2.4 and i inject arguments this way `arguments:
            - "@some_repository"
            - "@request"`

Answer (score 1):

Please try one of the follow approach to deal with that exception:

- Remove `scope: request` and change `arguments: [@form.factory, @request]` to `arguments: [@form.factory, @request=]`
- use Synchronized Service available since Symfony 2.3 where `synchronized: true` needs to be added to the service configuration and setter function to the class. Request is set by Symfony DI when available in scope. Reference  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html):

> ```
> services:     
>     property.value.form.resolver.number:
>         class: Frisbee\ProductBundle\Form\Resolver\PropertyTypeFormResolverNumber
>         arguments: [@form.factory]
>         synchronized: true
>         calls:
>             - [setRequest, ["@?request="]]
> ```

```
    /**
     * @param Request $request
    */
    public function setRequest(Request $request = null)
    {
        if ($request !== null) {
            $this->request = $request;
        }
    }
```

- adding `lazy: true` to the configuration may also help:

> ```
> services:
>     property.value.form.resolver.number:
>         class: Frisbee\ProductBundle\Form\Resolver\PropertyTypeFormResolverNumber
>         arguments: [@form.factory, @request]
>         scope: request
>         lazy: true
> ```