# Ajax errors on services since 2.4: custom event + request scope

Tags: php, symfony

Since I upgraded from Symfony 2.1 to 2.4, I'm faced with a quite unexpected error. For now I could only speculate on the reasons why it happens:

```
[2014-03-24 10:32:19] emergency.EMERGENCY: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException' with message 'You cannot create a service ("form.type.daterange") of an inactive scope ("request").' in D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1231
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2033): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getForm_Type_DaterangeService()
#1 D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\app\cache\dev\classes.php(1842): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('form.type.dater...')
#2 D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\app\cache\dev\classes.php(1807): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('resources.autol...')
#3 D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php(106): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners(NULL)
#4 D:\Users\abousquet\workspace\eportal\vendor\symfony\sy {"type":1,"file":"D:\\Users\\abousquet\\workspace\\eportal\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":1231} []
```

The error is triggered in DEV whenever I try to access any page using Ajax. It is triggered after the page is rendered (the action of the controller completes correctly and the error happens afterwards). This makes it hard as hell to understand when the error spawns.

The service **form.type.dateRange** is a custom form type that is also registered as an event subscriber. Here is its service definition:

```
<service id="form.type.dateRange" class="eportal\CoreBundle\Form\DateRangeType" scope="request">
    <argument type="service" id="calendar.conf.reader" />
    <tag name="form.type" alias="dateRange" />
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```

This service is registered on a custom event **resources.autoload** that is triggered in my main controller just before a page is rendered - but never when using Ajax pages.

As the logs put it, it seems the **request** service is not available at the time this service is requested. But when and why the hell is it requested ? It seems to me that removing that mysterious call would solve my problem.

The error will not pop if I unsubscribe the event registration or if I widen the scope. I strongly believe that the combination of custom event + request scope is somewhat at the source of my issue.

When I prevent the error on **form.type.dateRange**, some other service, registered on the same event with the same scope, fails instead. Thus a coding error inside my class seems strongly unlikely to me.

Last fun fact: The error triggers on pages when none of these failing services are actually used.

**Edit:**

Code where my custom event is triggered. It is an override of the **render()** method:

```
abstract class HTMLControllerAbstract extends CoreControllerAbstract
{
    ...

    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        $event = new FilterControllerEvent(
            $this->get('kernel'),
            array($this, 'render'),
            $this->getRequest(),
            HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST
        );

        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(StoreEvents::RESOURCES_AUTOLOAD, $event);

        $this->setReplacement('breadcrumb', $this->breadcrumb->getView());
        $this->setReplacement('javascripts', $this->javascriptResources);
        $this->setReplacement('stylesheets', $this->CSSResources);
        $this->setReplacement('see_also', $this->_getSeeAlso());

        return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

What works: Removing the 'request' scope from all services using the custom event. No error will be logged but I'm still worrying that two consecutive pages are treated with the same request service instance.

I still feel the solution to be somewhat insatisfying though. There is no clear reason why the **request** scope should fail with custom events.

**Accepted Response:**

As I suspected, the problem occured in a hidden sub-call that I still cannot completely figure out as of today. The solution? The solution provided by **Manolo Salsas** was the right one in the end, but I could not know at the time WHERE these 2 loc should be written. Now I know, it must be in app/AppKernel.php:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function initializeContainer()
    {
        parent::initializeContainer();
        $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request'); 
        $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
    }
}
```

Another solution that applies in my specific case, was to get rid of the **request** parameter from the form types that crashed. Since the request was used to populate automatically some of the form options, the solution was to populate these options manually, from anywhere but the service that subscribes to the custom event.

Comment: Do you get this error only in Dev environment ? It might be due to debug toolbar. Could you please try switching off debug toolbar and check if its the reason ?

Comment: also I had similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942738/error-you-cannot-create-a-service-templating-helper-assets-of-an-inactive-s

Comment: Although your reasoning somehow makes sense, disabling the toolbar solves nothing. I saw your error and your accepted response, but I don't understand where the correction took place. As far as I know my problem does not happen during CLI.

Comment: can you post some code in your even subscriber ?

Comment: My event subscriber service is the base Symfony 2.4 Event subscriber and I don't think posting its code would be relevant. I can and will however post the code called to trigger the custom event.

Comment: As of S2.4, you should use the [`request_stack`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request)

Comment: Dully noted. I had the hope that the problem would be resolved with this, but no. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `Request` object, you can extend `ContainerAware` and:

```
$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$this->getContainer()->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

Comment: The application would outright crash if that was the problem. Checked anyway, but the error is still here.

Comment: @Zephyr - Sorry. I was wrong again. The updated answer should work.

Comment: My project does not use Doctrine. I tried by injecting directly the service container instead, as you're suggesting, to no avail. I tried this line, too: if (!$incoming->hasScope('request')) throw new \Exception('exception thrown'); But no exception was thrown... Edited the question with more details.

Comment: @Zephyr - I've updated my answer (again) before your last comment

Comment: Found a solution (not yet sure if it fully works, though). Question edited.

Comment: @Zephyr - Congratulations. Anyway my answer should work too. No reason for down voting now.

Comment: Cancelled the down voting. But applying your code does not solve the issue, removing the 'request' scope from the service does.